# Subnet for logging/monitoring servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Just starting to move our first application to AWS. We have one public subnet (web servers) and two private subnets (for our app instances and databases). My query is where should we put our log management (greylog) and monitoring instances. Should we put them into our app instances subnet or create another private subnet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the same app subnet, but it is good to have separate subnet for separate services since it will helpful for scenarios like while debugging we can easily classify that requests coming from a particular CIDR range belongs to app subnet or monitoring subnet and we can also have the flexibility of blocking traffic through ACL which applies at subnet level.

Answer (score 0):

You can very well place the logging/monitoring servers in the one the existing private subnets as long as you have rightly sized the subnet CIDR block with enough IP addresses.

Refer this documentation for VPC/Subnet sizing
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html#vpc-sizing-ipv4